# Run current line or selection in shell then insert result in Emacs buffer (Acme workflow)

Tags: key-bindings, evil, region, shell-command, multiple-cursors

Given lines like these:

```
pwd

echo "Hello \
World"
```

in a buffer, I would like to do the following:

1. Put the cursor to the first line, then press `` C-` ``
2. Select lines 3-4 then press `` C-` ``

to send the line or selection to a shell `bash` and insert the output in the following line. Ideally, the terminal should be persistent, thus setting variables then reusing them is possible.

I found in Evil mode, I could type `!!sh` to do `1.` and `!sh` when a region is selected (however this replaces the command with the returned output), but couldn't figure out how to map `` C-` `` to `!!sh`. `:.w !sh` seems to be closer to what I wanted.

There seems to be an Emacs package `run-stuff` that offers similar functionality, but I'd rather use ways provided by Vanilla Emacs plus common Emacs packages such as `evil-mode`, `use-package` etc.

Ultimately, I'd like to embed an acme-like workflow into Emacs, where I can put a few short commands on an anchored top line, then run them while providing a selected text as input to the said command, and if possible, some other selected text (maybe using `multiselect`) as options to the command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`M-|` (`M-x shell-command-on-region`) runs a shell command using the region as stdin, display the output in the echo area, with a prefix arg, replace the region with the output.

Unlike your shell in a terminal, each use of `M-!` or `M-|`: start a shell such as `bash`, run the shell command, then kill the shell. And the region is data passed to the shell command, the content is arbitrary, for example,

```
ABCDE             M-| wc
{"type": "JSON"}  M-| jq
```

the above works because `wc` and `jq` read stdin as input, and since the executables `bash`, `ruby` and `python3` read stdin as corresponding programming code, you can run Bash/Ruby/Python code with `M-|`, e.g.,

```
echo "Bash"       M-| bash
puts "Ruby"       M-| ruby
print("Python")   M-| python3
```

In other words, `M-|` is simple and generic, so stick with it, if you need insert the output, simply copy-and-paste, though defining your own command isn't hard at all, e.g.,

```el
(defun your-shell-command-on-region ()
  "Like `shell-command-on-region' but insert output after the region."
  (declare (interactive-only t))
  (interactive)
  (let ((output-buffer (generate-new-buffer " *temp*")))
    (shell-command-on-region
     (region-beginning) (region-end)
     (read-shell-command "Shell command on region: ")
     output-buffer)
    (goto-char (region-end))
    (unless (bolp)
      (insert ?\n))
    (insert-buffer-substring output-buffer)
    (kill-buffer output-buffer)))
```

> Run current line or selection in shell then insert result in buffer in Emacs

Let's assuming the current line or selection are shell code

```el
(defun $ (b e)
  "Run current line or selection in shell and insert output."
  (interactive
   (if (use-region-p)
       (list (region-beginning) (region-end))
     (list (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position))))
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char e)
    (unless (bolp) (insert "\n"))
    (shell-command (buffer-substring-no-properties b e) t t)))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-c") #'$)
```

A cool idea is **update** the output in-place (like Org Mode Babel), that is, delete the old output then insert the new output,

```el
(defun $$ (b e)
  "Run current line as shell code and insert/update output."
  (interactive (list (line-beginning-position)
                     (line-end-position)))
  (save-excursion
    ;; delete old output
    (delete-region
     (progn (forward-line) (point))
     (progn (while (get-text-property (point) '$$)
              (forward-line))
            (point)))

    (unless (bolp) (insert "\n"))
    (let* ((command (buffer-substring-no-properties b e))
           (output (with-temp-buffer
                     (shell-command command t t)
                     (buffer-string)))
           (start (point)))
      (insert (propertize output '$$ t 'rear-nonsticky t))
      (pulse-momentary-highlight-region start (point)))))
```

Try it with `date`.

> Ultimately, I'd like to embed an acme-like workflow into Emacs, where I can put a few short commands on an anchored top line, then run them while providing a selected text as input to the said command,

`M-|` does this, though the user interface is different, the input is from the region, the command is from the minibuffer, the output is to echo area.

To implement the similar workflow you described, get started with three buffers for input/command/output, the code should be straightforward.

Comment: Thanks! My elisp-Fu isn't strong enough yet to implement something like your `$$`. That was very cool! `C-c C-c` is bound in org-mode, so I am binding it to ``C-` ``. I tested `$$` on a line `ls ~/Desktop` but it failed; I wonder if we can treat `~` or anything in the line as string literals.

Comment: @hyiltiz It should not fail, behind the scenes, it's simply `M-! ls ~/Desktop`, you obviously want `~` to be expand into your home directory and shell does it for you. You can prevent the expansion via quote, e.g., `echo '~/Desktop'`.